# How to add xmlns attribute to the root element?

Tags: c#, xml

I have to write xml file like the fallowing

```
<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Status>Enabled</Status>
</VersioningConfiguration>
```

please any one help me to write like above.

Comment: Well I'd use LINQ to XML. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have used linq but I am geting the xmlns for <status> also. I don't want for child elements I need only for root element

Comment: If you've tried something already but it's not working, you should show what you've tried. Note that the document you've shown includes the `Status` element in the namespace due to namespace defaulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to XML makes this trivial - you just specify the namespace for the element, and it will include the `xmlns="..."` automatically. You *can* give it an alias, but that's slightly harder. To produce the exact document you've shown, you just need:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/";
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ns + "VersioningConfiguration",
       new XElement(ns + "Status", "Enabled")));
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

LINQ to XML is by far the best XML API I've used, particularly in its handling of namespaces. Just say no to `XmlDocument` :)

Comment: Hi,its working I got another problem like after creation of the xml file (using above format)then how can I add the new child for that.That child also doesn't contains xmlns attribute.

Comment: @user3085714: Just keep using the namespace, as I've shown for the `Status` element. Do you understand that `Status` is within the same namespace as `VersioningConfiguration`, because it inherits it as a default?

Answer (score 0):

```
 XNamespace Name = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/";
 XDocument doc=new XDocument();
 XElement X1=new XElement(Name+"VersioningConfiguration","" );
 XElement X2=new XElement(Name+"Status","Enabled");
 X1.Add(X2);
 doc.Add(X1);
```

Comment: Hi,its working I got another problem like after creation of the xml file (using above format)then how can I add the new child for that.That child also doesn't contains xmlns attribute.

Comment: Make a simple XElement like:- XElement Temp=new XElement("ABC","XYZ")     and add it to the pre existing elements like X1.Add(Temp); hope it willwork for you.